# How to add an image in the first react component and ignore in rest of the components using map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, ecmascript-6, react-component

I'm trying to add content into a component using json file where I require only the first component to have the cover image and rest of the components to ignore it.

```
Schema:  "TrackList": [
    {
      "CourseNo": "1",
      "CourseName": "C++ Programming with DataStructures",
      "CoverImg":"example.com/cover.jpg"
    },
    {
      "CourseNo": "2",
      "CourseName": "Competitive Programming"
    },
    {
      "CourseNo": "3",
      "CourseName": "Java"
    }
  ]
```

the below code renders as required but it also adds blank image into components except the first one.

```
render(){
 const { Data } = this.props;
    const Courses = Data.TrackList.map(course => {
      return (
        <li>
          <span>Course {course.CourseNo}</span>
          <a href='#path-10'>{course.CourseName}</a>
          <img src={course.CoverImg}/>
        </li>
      ) 
    });


return(
 <div className='col-md-4 right-pannel'>
    <ul>
    {Courses}
    </ul>
 </div>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) calls the provided callback function with the current array index (as the second argument). The first index of an array is `0`, so you just need to add some logic that makes sure the image is only added when the index is equal to 0, like this:

```js
  const Courses = Data.TrackList.map((course, i) => {
    return (
      <li>
        <span>Course {course.CourseNo}</span>
        <a href='#path-10'>{course.CourseName}</a>
        { i === 0 && <img src={course.CoverImg}/> }
      </li>
      ) 
    });
```

And here's a slightly modified version of your code turned into a runnable snippet:

```js
const Data = {"TrackList": [{"CourseNo": "1","CourseName": "C++ Programming with DataStructures","CoverImg":"example.com/cover.jpg"},{"CourseNo": "2","CourseName": "Competitive Programming"},{"CourseNo": "3","CourseName": "Java"}]}

const Courses = Data.TrackList.map((course, i) =>
  <li>
    <span>CourseNo: {course.CourseNo}</span>
    <span> | CourseName: {course.CourseName}</span>
    { i === 0 && <span> | CoverImg: {course.CoverImg}</span> }
  </li>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <div className='col-md-4 right-pannel'>
    <ul>
    {Courses}
    </ul>
  </div>,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or more generic solution can be the below code, as can be seen in your data, other object does not have **CoverImg** key.

```
const Courses = Data.TrackList.map(course => {
      return (
        <li>
          <span>Course {course.CourseNo}</span>
          <a href='#path-10'>{course.CourseName}</a>
          {course.CoverImg && <img src={course.CoverImg}/>}
        </li>
      ) 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put condition with && to render only object which is having image

**Optimized**

-Unique key for every row

-&& condition for available image path

-another way removing `return(){}`

Code

```
  render() {
    const { Data } = this.props;
    const Courses = Data.TrackList.map(course => (
      <li key={course.CourseNo}>
        <span>Course {course.CourseNo}</span>
        <a href="#path-10">{course.CourseName}</a>
        {course.CoverImg && <img src={course.CoverImg} alt="imgicon" />}
      </li>
    ));

    return (
      <div className="col-md-4 right-pannel">
        <ul>{Courses}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```